# Clearing input in vuejs form

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

Just completed a todolist tutorial. 
When submitting the form the input field doesn't clear.

After trying both:

```
    document.getElementById("todo-field").reset();
    document.getElementById("#todo-field").value = "";
```

The input field properly clears but it also deletes the todo.

It seems to delete the input field before it has time to push the new todo in the todos.text array.

Would love some input guys! Thanks!!

```
<template>
  <form id="todo-field" v-on:submit="submitForm">
    <input type="text" v-model="text">
  </form>
     <ul>
       <li v-for="todo in todos">
        <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" v-model="todo.completed">
        <span :class="{completed: todo.completed}" class="col-md-6">
            <label @dblclick="deleteTodo(todo)">
                {{todo.text}}
            </label>
        </span>

       </li>
     </ul>
```

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'todos',
      data () {
        return {
          text: '',
          todos: [
          {
      text:'My Todo One',
      completed: false
    },
    {
      text:'My Todo Two',
      completed: false
    },
    {
      text:'My Todo Three',
      completed: false
    }
  ]// End of array
}
  },
    methods: {
    deleteTodo(todo){
        this.todos.splice(this.todos.indexOf(todo),1);
    },
    submitForm(e){
        this.todos.push(
            {
                text: this.text,
                completed: false
            }
        );
        //document.getElementById("todo-field").reset();
        document.getElementById("#todo-field").value = "";

        // To prevent the form from submitting
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What you need is to set `this.text` to an empty string in your `submitForm` function:

```
submitForm(e){
    this.todos.push(
        {
            text: this.text,
            completed: false
        }
    );
    this.text = "";

    // To prevent the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Remember that binding works both ways: The (input) view can update the (string) model, or the model can update the view.

Comment: @TonyRositano: You're welcome. Can you please accept the answer if it did indeed work? Thanks.

Comment: @Tony Rositano: 
Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation). In other words, if you accept the answer, please click the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Gotcha thanks! Cannot upvote yet...not enough credentials! Soon will do!

Comment: The problem with this manner is that validation is then triggered and in my case "The field cannot be null"

Comment: Same validation issue when giving an empty string value

Answer (score 52):

These solutions are good but if you want to go for less work then you can use `$refs`

```
<form ref="anyName" @submit="submitForm">
</form>

<script>
   methods: {
      submitForm(){
         // Your form submission
         this.$refs.anyName.reset(); // This will clear that form
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: This is the best answer here, in my opinion, but I wish there were a way to modify the behavior such that the form inputs are reverted to their _initial state_ (when the DOM was first rendered), and not simply cleared outright. My use-case is that I want the user to be able to "undo" any changes made to the form since page-load, without completely resetting all inputs to "no selection". It seems I'll need a different approach, but thanks for sharing this technique!

Comment: @BenJohnson what about using `defaultForm = Object.freeze({...})` when creating a form with default values, assigning this to a form using `form = Object.assign({}, this.defaultForm)` and then keeping the `reset()` like it's in that example? Wouldn't be what you want to achieve? The resetting would be then (by following my example) `this.$refs.form.reset()`. `ref` in `html` would be to `form`, like `ref="form"`.

Comment: If you use vee-validate (currently in version 4.5.11) it's not reset() but resetForm(), hence this.$refs.anyName.resetForm()

Answer (score 30):

Assuming that you have a form that is huge or simply you do not want to reset each form field one by one, you can reset all the fields of the form by iterating through the fields one by one

```
var self = this;
Object.keys(this.data.form).forEach(function(key,index) {
    self.data.form[key] = '';
});
```

The above will reset all fields of the given `this.data.form` object to empty string. Let's say there are one or two fields that you selectively want to set to a specific value in that case inside the above block you can easily put a condition based on **field name**

```
if(key === "country") 
   self.data.form[key] = 'Canada';
else 
   self.data.form[key] = '';
```

Or if you want to reset the field based on type and you have boolean and other field types in that case

```
if(typeof self.data.form[key] === "string") 
   self.data.form[key] = ''; 
else if (typeof self.data.form[key] === "boolean") 
   self.data.form[key] = false;
```

For more type info see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

A basic `vuejs` template and script sample would look as follow

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="User first name" v-model="data.form.firstName">
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="User last name" v-model="data.form.lastName">
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="User phone" v-model="data.form.phone">
      <input type="submit" class="button is-info" value="Add">
      <input type="button" class="button is-warning" @click="resetForm()" value="Reset Form">
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

See ow the `@submit.prevent="onSubmit"` is used in the form element. That would by default, prevent the form submission and call the `onSubmit` function.

Let's assume we have the following  for the above

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        data: {
          form: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            phone: ''
          }
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit: function() {
        console.log('Make API request.')
        this.resetForm(); //clear form automatically after successful request
      },
      resetForm() {
        console.log('Reseting the form')
        var self = this; //you need this because *this* will refer to Object.keys below`

        //Iterate through each object field, key is name of the object field`
        Object.keys(this.data.form).forEach(function(key,index) {
          self.data.form[key] = '';
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can call the `resetForm` from anywhere and it will reset your form fields.

Comment: I find this a much better solution. DRY. Thanks!

Comment: One of my `input` fields is `required` and is getting marked after clearing the form. But the submit call is `@submit.prevent`

Answer (score 10):

For reset all field in one form you can use `event.target.reset()`

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',    
    data(){
 return{        
            name : null,
     lastname : null,
     address : null
 }
    },
    methods: {
        submitForm : function(event){
            event.preventDefault(),
            //process...             
            event.target.reset()
        }
    }

});
```

```css
form input[type=text]{border-radius:5px; padding:6px; border:1px solid #ddd}
form input[type=submit]{border-radius:5px; padding:8px; background:#060; color:#fff; cursor:pointer; border:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<form id="todo-field" v-on:submit="submitForm">
        <input type="text" v-model="name"><br><br>
        <input type="text" v-model="lastname"><br><br>
        <input type="text" v-model="address"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

**Markup**

```
<template lang="pug">
  form
    input.input(type='text' v-model='formData.firstName')
    input.input(type='text' v-model='formData.lastName')
    button(@click='resetForm') Reset Form
</template>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
  const initFromData = { firstName: '', lastName: '' };
  
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        formData: Object.assign({}, initFromData),
      };
    },
    methods: {
      resetForm() {
        // if shallow copy
        this.formData = Object.assign({}, initFromData);
  
        // if deep copy
        // this.formData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initFromData));
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Read the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710).

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
this.$refs['refFormName'].resetFields();
```

this work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution is only for components**

If we toggle(show/hide) components using booleans then data is also removed.
No need to clean the form fields.

I usually make components and initialize them using booleans.
e.g.

```
<template>
    <button @click="show_create_form = true">Add New Record</button
    <create-form v-if="show_create_form" />
</template>


<script>
...
data(){
   return{
       show_create_form:false //making it false by default
   }
},
methods:{
    submitForm(){
      //...
      this.axios.post('/submit-form-url',data,config)
           .then((response) => {
               this.show_create_form= false; //hide it again after success.
               //if you now click on add new record button then it will show you empty form
           }).catch((error) => {
              //
           })
    }
}
...
</script>
```

When use clicks on edit button then this boolean becomes true and after successful submit I change it to false again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where i was working with a custom component and i needed to clear the form data.

But only if the page was in 'create' form state, and if the page was not being used to edit an existing item. So I made a method.

I called this method inside a watcher on custom component file, and not the vue  page that uses the custom component. If that makes sense.

The entire form $ref was only available to me on the Base Custom Component.

```
<!-- Custom component HTML -->
<template>
  <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" @submit.prevent>
    <slot v-bind="{ formItem, formState, valid }"></slot>
  </v-form>
</template>

watch: {
  value() {
    // Some other code here
    this.clearFormDataIfNotEdit(this)
    // Some other code here too
  }
}
... some other stuff ....

methods: {
  clearFormDataIfNotEdit(objct) {
    if (objct.formstate === 'create' && objct.formItem.id === undefined) {
       objct.$refs.form.reset()
    }
  },
}
```

Basically i checked to see if the form data had an ID, if it did not, and the state was on create, then call `the obj.$ref.form.reset()` if i did this directly in the watcher, then it would be `this.$ref.form.reset()` obvs.

But you can only call the $ref from the page which it's referenced.
Which is what i wanted to call out with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in `Vue 3`.

html:

```
  <input type="text" v-model="state.name">
```

js:

```
import {reactive} from "vue";

const state = reactive({
    name: ""
})

axios.post('/contact', state)
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
            state.name = ""
        }
    })
```

Response status 200 being a successful submission of the form input. `state.name` is reactive and will be set to `""` if the submission is successful.

Comment: This gives me validation errors since I'm giving the input an empty value

Answer (score 0):

if your using `vue.js v-form` you can simply do like

```
this.form.reset()
```

Documentation
[Vform - Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vform)