# Cleanest way to reset form and easily maintain as it grows

Tags: vuejs2

I am creating an input form with VueJS and the form contains about 10+ input fields. I have a reset button that, when clicked, will "reset" the form's value to either an empty string, null, or boolean (i have checkboxes in actual form).

What I have currently works fine, but I can't help and wonder that this method is going to be hard to maintain once I get additional fields added to the form. Every time I get a new field to add, I will have to also update my reset method with that new field. *I do want to keep things simple, so I also don't want to over complicate things, either...so maybe keeping this approach is easier to read for junior devs..

**Is this a good approach?**

Here's my current code:

> Script section:

```
..snip...
data() {
    return {
      show: true,
      products: [],
      subjects: [],
      form: {
        product: '',
        subject: ''
      }
    }
},
created() {
    this.getProducts() <--- getting products from an api
    this.getSubjects() < -- getting subjects from an api
    ..snip..
},
  methods: {
    resetForm() {
      this.form = {
        product: '',
        subject: ''
      }
      // Trick to reset/clear native browser form validation state
      this.show = false
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.show = true
      })
    }
...snip...
```

> Template section:

```
<form v-if="show">
..snip..
<label for="product_select_input">Product:</label>
          <select
            id="product_select_input"
            v-model="form.product"
            required
          >
            <option disabled value="">Select</option>
            <option
              v-for="product in products"
              :key="product.product_id"
              :value="product.product_id"
              >{{ product.product_name }}</option
            >
          </select>
..snip..
<button @click.prevent="resetForm">
            Reset Form
          </button>
...snip...
</form>
```

Comment: Seems to be a close duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518609/clearing-input-in-vuejs-form

Comment: Isn't a reset button on a form a [horrible UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/93671/2993)?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest (and presumably most robust) approach I've been using to reset form and/or `data` values is by **merging** the initial one (accessible via [`$options`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options)) **into** the "dirty" [`$data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data) states.

```js
Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.call(this));
```

Explanations:

1. [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) as the merging strategy, if you would. Feel free to use third-party libraries like [lodash.merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.merge) or [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge) for advanced merging.
2. `this.$data` refers to the current Vue instance `data`. An excerpt from the [official doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> After the instance is created, the original data object can be accessed as `vm.$data`.

And that is why you don't simply pass `this`, even though it is the Vue instance.

3. `this.$options.data` is the data "factory" that lets you create a fresh copy of the initial data.

For this to work though, you'll need the [`data` defined as a
function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function).

The [`call(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) part is just a Function prototype that allows you to call a function with a given `this` value, in this case the Vue instance. This is particularly required when you are referencing the Vue instance from within the `data` object while initializing, for instance:

`````
````js
data() {
  return {
    pageTitle: this.$route.meta.title
  }
},

// Or, the ES6 equivalent
data: vm => ({
  pageTitle: vm.$route.meta.title
})
````
At this point, without the given `this` context, it will actually throw an exception.
`````

To make this even more handy, you could extend the Vue prototype and start invoking it whenever and wherever you need to reset the `data`.

### Full demo

```js
Vue.prototype.$resetVueData = function() {
  if (typeof this.$options.data !== 'function') {
    console.warn('No `data` option being specified in this Vue instance.', this);
    return false;
  }

  Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.call(this));
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: vm => ({
    show: false,
    products: [],
    subjects: [],
    form: {
      product: '',
      subject: ''
    }
  }),

  methods: {
    resetForm() {
      this.$resetVueData();

      // The rest of your form-resetting logic goes here
      // Like Vuetify's form.resetValidation, or state restoration of complex data
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <pre>{{$data}}</pre>

  <button @click="show = !show">Show/Hide</button>
  <button @click="products.push(Date.now())">Add random product</button>
  <button @click="subjects.push(Date.now() / 2)">Add random subject</button>
  <button @click="form.product = 'Some product'; form.subject = 'Subject1'">Add form data</button>
  <button @click="resetForm">RESET</button>
</div>
```

---

**P.S.** I'm using inline value assignment only for demo purposes and brevity reason.

**P.P.S.** This merging strategy will affect the whole `data`, so if you need to target specific objects within it, you could add another argument in the method for the target's key name, and use it with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) on the `this.$data` while merging. But there should be more ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many solutions, including 
`Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.call(this))`
If your data needs to be empty strings, you can also recreate the object by using a for loop. However, I like this solution:

```
    data () {
      return {
       form: this.getEmptyForm()
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getEmptyForm () {
       return {
        product: '',
        subject: ''
       }
      }, 
      resetForm () {
       this.form = this.getEmptyForm()
      }
    }
```